# Semi-transparent objects in tile based rpg game

Tags: java, android, canvas, bitmap

I am currently working on a simple, tile based rpg for android devices. I have stumbled across an error which I cannot solve efficiently.

**Rendering Mechanics**

I am currently using android's `Canvas` implementation to render everything in my game. I load the tile map into a bitmap using an open source TMX loader I found (not really relevant which one). The TMX loader loads the map file and produces a bitmap of the data stored in the tmx file. I am using [Tiled](http://www.mapeditor.org) to create my maps. The game first draws this bitmap produced by the tmx loader and then all other objects (including the player) on top of the map.

**The Problem**

As suggested in the title, this causes problems for semi-transparent tiles such as in this map:[image]

The gray box is where entities collide with the well in the center of the map.

This map would be rendered like this:
[image]

The arrow is the player - part of the player should be drawn under the wooden beams of the well but still over the grass

**I am struggling to find a way draw the player under the wooden beams of the well and over the grass. If anyone could give me some advice on how to do this, it would be greatly appreciated.**

**What I have tried**

In another game I was developing, I created an object layer on tiled which would contain rectangles where the map should be drawn over the player. This worked although it caused the frame rate to drop quite a lot and it is difficult to precisely plot the rectangles over the required areas.

Comment: You need to sort the player and transparent tiles via their y position, then render them in order from top to bottom. That way the further up the screen the earlier the image is drawn, thus transparent object will be correctly drawn on top.

Comment: @Blindman67 Doesn't that mean I will have to re create the entire map every frame which will kill the fps? The game just about runs @ 30fps on a 16x16 map which doesn't even fill the screen.

Comment: Afraid so, but if render time is an issue you can check where the entities that can be covered are and then only redraw the parts that are on top only where and when needed.

Comment: Thanks for the idea @Blindman67 . I will attempt to implement this at some point